# FB SDK produces a PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, fbsdk

First noticed [27-Mar-2017 17:47:16 GMT+0] a FB SDK integration that worked very well allowing people to login to our site via their Facebook account just stopped working. The server logs show the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in fb-sdk/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 191
```

We have not done any relevant code change that should have initiated it.
Have we missed an upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested fix for line 191-193:

```
if (isset($response->access_token)) {
return new FacebookSession($response->access_token);
}
```

You can also try converting `$response` to array but that won't be optimized solution. So, go ahead and try aforementioned solution.

Or try replacing in `src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php`

```
 if (isset($response['access_token'])) {
    return new FacebookSession($response['access_token']);
```

WITH

```
  $accessToken = null;
  if (is_object($response) && isset($response->access_token)) {
    $accessToken = $response->access_token;
  } elseif (is_array($response) && isset($response['access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $response['access_token'];
  }
  if (isset($accessToken)) {
    return new FacebookSession($accessToken);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggested solution. Have you tested this yourself with Facbeook login? Do you have any idea why it suddenly stopped working?

Comment: There is no official upgrade announced by Facebook but we too saw this error with our projects this morning and this fix worked for us. I hope this will help you for now.

Comment: This seems to be working on our dev machine and soon we'll deploy and I'll update this comment. Thank you very much for it. Which version of the SDK have you been using?

Comment: We always love to use latest stuff ;) So, Latest version of Facebook SDK v5 and graph version is 2.8 I guess.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was bcz we were with an older v4. Thanks for the info. It now works live. Great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "$response['access_token']" with "$response->access_token" on line 186 and 187 in FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to migrate to SDK 5
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login